# electron.js - BrowserWindow viewport size shrinks by 1px when it is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I have a frameless electron.js window here (main.js):

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    useContentSize: true,
    frame: false,
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html').then();
}
```

I also created a main element that spans the entire width of the body, and that includes a draggable title bar:

```html
...
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="titlebar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

The created window has a shadow, but it looks kind of unnatural without a highlighting border, so tried creating a border around `.main`. The CSS to the entire construct looks like this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.titlebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;

    background-color: white;
}
```

Initially everything looks fine and as intended:
[image: Window with solid border]

But when the window is resized the border at the bottom and right simply disappears:
[image: Bottom and right border disappeared]

What is the issue here? How can I fix it?

Comment: You can try setting  position of `.main` to `position: fixed;` with top, right, bottom and left set to 0.  Instead of setting width and height to 100%.

Comment: @Timur the issue persists, but thank you for the suggestion; sadly I'll need to find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that apparently setting the width and height of the `.main` element (or even the `html` element for that matter) down by one pixel and using `transparent: "true"` fixes the issue, but also disables maximizing/restoring and snapping to edges. This is a solution but not the best one by far.